# From Dialogflow to Alexa, how to create lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dialogflow-es, alexa-skills-kit

I have built a simple chatbot with Dialogflow and I have exported the json file to integrate it into alexa.
I created the skill with no problem but now I don't know how create the lambda function code for the endpoint (I create the function, but I don't know the code I have to write in).

Do you know some code for this dialogflow integration?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's some great resources out there already with code to get you started. I'd recommend reading as much documentation as possible. Check out these links, the github repo has some great examples. For hosting I use the serverless framework to deploy to AWS. Highly recommend checking that out if you're a beginner to this.

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/fulfillment
https://medium.com/faun/building-chatbot-with-google-dialogflow-with-aws-lambda-e19872e1589